# How to create a 2D numpy array of pixel values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a 2d numpy array of all the pixel locations for a 512 x 512 image. Meaning there would be 512<sup>2</sup> or 262,144 values. It may be slightly more if the x and y zeroes are considered, but you get the idea.

To do it manually would be like this `pixels = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 2], [0,3], [0,4]])` all the way to the end. But obviously I need to automate it. The order of pixels doesn't matter though. It needs to be in that "format" so I can access the pixels x and y values by 0 and 1 index i.e. `pixels[0][0]` for the first pixel's x value and `pixels[0][1]` for the first pixel's y value.

Comment: simply use `for`-loops to automate it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
pixels = np.array([[x, y] for y in range(512) for x in range(512)])
```

Note that you can modify it for different x or y values.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` is openly used to process and manipulate **images** through multi-dimensional `arrays`, since they are very *useful* to storing *values* as pixels (`rgb`, `rgba`, `greyscale`, etc ...)

RGB:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> array = np.zeros([100, 200, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> array[:,:100] = [255, 128, 0] #Orange left side
>>> array[:,100:] = [0, 0, 255]   #Blue right side
>>> img = Image.fromarray(array)
>>> array[:,:100] = [100, 128, 0]
>>> array[:,100:] = [0, 0, 200]
>>> img = Image.fromarray(array)
>>> img.save('img.png')
```

[image: im1]

GREYSCALE:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> array = np.zeros([100, 200], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> # Set grey value to black or white depending on x position
>>> for x in range(200):
>>>     for y in range(100):
>>>         if (x % 16) // 8 == (y % 16) // 8:
>>>             array[y, x] = 0
>>>         else:
>>>             array[y, x] = 255
>>>
>>> img = Image.fromarray(array)
>>> img.save('img.png')
```

[image: im2]