# Godot how to get screenshot of camera viewport as a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, screenshot, viewport, godot

I have set up a basic scene in Godot as below:

[Godot Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2fP5.png)

with a floor, some obstacles (boxes) and a camera.

(I am using python as a scripting language in Godot)

I found a way to get a screenshot of the camera viewport like so:

```
(in Python _process function...)
old_clear_mode = self.viewport.get_clear_mode()
self.viewport.set_clear_mode(Viewport.CLEAR_MODE_ONLY_NEXT_FRAME)
img = self.viewport.get_texture().get_data()
self.viewport.set_clear_mode(old_clear_mode)
img.flip_y()
img.save_png("temp.png")
img = Image.open("temp.png").convert("RGB")
sharpened_img = self.sharpen_edges(img)
plt.imsave('temp2.png', sharpened_img)
(...)
```

I save the  as a png, and immediately after I load that very same png to apply a transformation fro edge detection, then save it again.

This method takes close to 0.5s so it is rather slow.

***The question is:***
Is there a faster way to convert the "screenshot" to a numpy array, in order to apply my transformation?

*NOTE:*
I am trying to make this run at close to (if not at) real-time speeds, so speed optimizations are of the essence.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following links will help you:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194210/how-to-create-a-2d-numpy-array-of-pixel-values)

[Link2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-images-to-numpy-array/)